# Apply number ceiling/threshold to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda, apply

I have a dataframe with scores of three persons (John, Terry, Henry) from day 1 to day 7.

```
        1     2     3     4     5     6      7
John    1.3   2.8   3.0   4.4   2.6   3.1    4.8
Terry   1.1   2.3   4.1   5.5   3.7   2.1    3.8
Henry   0.3   1.0   2.0   3.0   2.7   1.1    2.8
```

How do I set a score ceiling such that **once a score hits > 2.5, all scores from that day onwards is set to 3 no matter what the score is**

The output should be:

```
        1     2     3     4     5     6      7
John    1.3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0    3.0
Terry   1.1   2.3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0    3.0
Henry   0.3   1.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   3.0    3.0
```

I tried to apply first define a function and use np.apply(threshold_1, axis=1) but it didn't work:

```
def threshold_1(x):
    if (x > 2.5 & x+1 < 2.5):
        return 3
    if (x > 2.5 & x+1 > 2.5):
        return 3
    else:
        return x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.mask(df.gt(2.5).cumsum(1).gt(0), 3)
#same as
#df = df.mask((df > 2.5).cumsum(axis=1) > 0, 3)
print (df)
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7
John   1.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Terry  1.1  2.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Henry  0.3  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

**Detail**:

First compare by `2.5` all values by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
print (df.gt(2.5))
           1      2      3     4     5      6     7
John   False   True   True  True  True   True  True
Terry  False  False   True  True  True  False  True
Henry  False  False  False  True  True  False  True
```

Then get [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) by columns by `axis=1`:

```
print (df.gt(2.5).cumsum(axis=1))
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7
John   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
Terry  0  0  1  2  3  3  4
Henry  0  0  0  1  2  2  3
```

And compare with `0`  by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
print (df.gt(2.5).cumsum(axis=1).gt(0))
           1      2      3     4     5     6     7
John   False   True   True  True  True  True  True
Terry  False  False   True  True  True  True  True
Henry  False  False  False  True  True  True  True
```

Last replace `True`s by `3` by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
print (df.mask(df.gt(2.5).cumsum(1).gt(0), 3))
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7
John   1.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Terry  1.1  2.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Henry  0.3  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

---

For improve performance is possible use `numpy`:

```
a = df.values
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.cumsum(a > 2.5, axis=1) > 0, 3, a), 
                   index=df.index,
                   columns=df.columns)
print (df1)

         1    2    3    4    5    6    7
John   1.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Terry  1.1  2.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Henry  0.3  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: Is it possible to instead of masking all the values to be 3, we just fixed the value? So for "Terry" on day 3, the value from day 3 onwards would be FIXED at 4.1.  

I tried replacing "3" with "df" but it doesn't work:

df.mask(df.gt(2.5).cumsum(1).gt(0), df)

Comment: I think the best is create new question, I think get more nice answers.

Comment: Already made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811596/pandas-dataframe-threshold-keep-number-fixed-if-exceed

Answer (score 0):

We can using `idxmax`

```
s=df.gt(2.5).idxmax(1)
for x in list(range(len(s))):
    df.loc[s.index[x],s[x]:]=3

df
Out[585]: 
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7
John   1.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Terry  1.1  2.3  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
Henry  0.3  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```