# Pandas dataframe threshold -- Keep number fixed if exceed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataframe with scores of three persons (John, Terry, Henry) from day 1 to day 7.

```
          1     2     3     4     5     6      7
John    1.3   2.8   3.0   4.4   2.6   3.1    4.8
Terry   1.1   2.3   4.1   5.5   3.7   2.1    3.8
Henry   0.3   1.0   2.0   3.0   2.7   1.1    2.8
```

How do I set a score ceiling such **that once a score hits > 2.5, all scores from that day onwards is FIXED no matter what the score is**

The output should be:

```
          1     2     3     4     5     6      7
John    1.3   2.8   2.8   2.8   2.8   2.8    2.8
Terry   1.1   2.3   4.1   4.1   4.1   4.1    4.1
Henry   0.3   1.0   2.0   3.0   3.0   3.0    3.0
```

Tried the following didn't work. I first do a boolean on all numbers > 2.5 to "1", then apply a mask to the cumulative sum:

```
df = df.mask((df > 2.5).cumsum(axis=1) > 0, df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find first non `NaN` value by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with `bfill` and select first column by `iloc`:

```
m = (df > 2.5).cumsum(axis=1) > 0

s = df.where(m).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (s)
John     2.8
Terry    4.1
Henry    3.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64

df = df.mask(m, s, axis=0)
```

Or [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) mask and forward filling `NaN`s to last values:

```
m = (df > 2.5).cumsum(axis=1) > 0
df = df.mask(m.shift(axis=1).fillna(False)).ffill(axis=1)
print (df)
         1    2    3    4    5    6    7
John   1.3  2.8  2.8  2.8  2.8  2.8  2.8
Terry  1.1  2.3  4.1  4.1  4.1  4.1  4.1
Henry  0.3  1.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: First method just fills up 2.5

Comment: What is `s` ? I add it to answer.